# Disable JavaScript when running Cucumber tests

Tags: javascript, selenium, cucumber, capybara

I am using Capybara and Cucumber to run some integration tests, one of which requires JavaScript to be disabled, I can achieve this manually by going to developer tools and disabling JS (Chrome), but how can I automate this process. I would like an option to start a browser up with JS disabled or enable/disable mid test

```
Capybara.register_driver :chrome do |app|
  chrome_binary = ENV["HENDRICKS_CHROME_BINARY"]

  if chrome_binary.nil?
    Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, :browser => :chrome)
  else
    capabilities = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.chrome(
      "chromeOptions" => {
        "binary" => chrome_binary + "/Contents/MacOS/Chromium"
      }
    )
    Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, :browser => :chrome, :desired_capabilities => capabilities)
  end
end
```

Is this possible with Chrome as my browser?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have done to disable JS:

```
Capybara.register_driver :js_disabled do |app|
  chrome_binary = ENV["HENDRICKS_CHROME_BINARY"]

  if chrome_binary.nil?
    Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, :browser => :chrome)
  else
    capabilities = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.chrome(
      "chromeOptions" => {
        "prefs" => {
          'profile.managed_default_content_settings.javascript' => 2
        },
        "binary" => chrome_binary + "/Contents/MacOS/Chromium"
       }
    )
    Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, :browser => :chrome, :desired_capabilities => capabilities)
  end
end
```

Note the prefs object passed via the chromeOptions.

Comment: Note: in recent Chrome versions in w3c mode `chromeOptions` should be `goog:chromeOptions`, or start using the `Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options` class, instead of desired capabilities, which will handle setting the correct key for you - https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara/blob/master/lib/capybara/registrations/drivers.rb#L20